# How do I get images to show on my django app?

Tags: python, django, image

On my Django app, I am trying to make an eBay type of site that lets people post listings with pictures and bid on them. Everything works except posting an image. The image won't show and I do not know if it's the HTML or the python. If you have any questions let me know.

Html code:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Create listing</h2>

</div>
<div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'submit' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Title of the lisiting..." name="title" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" placeholder="Description..." name="description" required></textarea>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="category" required>
              <option>Fashion</option>
              <option>Tools</option>
              <option>Toys</option>
              <option>Electronics</option>
              <option>Home accessories</option>
              <option>Books</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Initial Bid</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Starting bid..." name="price" required>
          </div>
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Image link (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="https://blah-blah.jpg..." name="link">
          </div>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>

      </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the python function for making listings:

```
def create(request):
    try:
        w = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
        wcount=len(w)
    except:
        wcount=None
    return render(request,"auctions/create.html",{
        "wcount":wcount
    })
```

Comment: Maybe you can learn from this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012123/image-uploaded-but-not-saved-in-media-and-database-django?r=SearchResults

Comment: Where exactly are you showing the image?

Comment: I'm trying to show an image of the item that I'm putting up for sale

Comment: And where is that image stored, how is it put there?