# cannot get image to upload to folder in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a personal training website and am having trouble getting the profile pic to upload

my form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="updateProfile" method="post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="gym">Main Gym</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gym" placeholder="Enter gym name" name="gym" id="gym">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="last name">Qualifications</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <textarea name="qualifications" rows="10" cols="130" name="qualifications" id="qualifications"></textarea>
        
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="last name">About Me</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">          
          <textarea name="aboutme" rows="10" cols="130" id="aboutme"></textarea>
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="servicedetails">Service Details</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
              <textarea name="servicedetails" rows="10" cols="130" id="servicedetails"></textarea>
              
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="avatar">Choose a profile picture:</label>
       <div class="form-group">             
<input type="file"
       id="avatar" name="avatar"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
            </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

models.py:

```
class trainerabout(models.Model):
    userID = models.IntegerField()
    gym = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    qualifications = models.TextField()
    aboutme = models.TextField()
    servicedetails = models.TextField()
    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

added this to urls.py

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
def updateProfile(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            gym = request.POST['gym']
            qualifications = request.POST['qualifications']
            aboutme = request.POST['aboutme']
            servicedetails = request.POST['servicedetails']
            avatar = request.POST['avatar']
            
            trainer = trainerabout(gym=gym, qualifications=qualifications, aboutme=aboutme, servicedetails=servicedetails, profilepic=avatar, userID=request.user.id)
            trainer.save()
   
        return render(request, 'updateProfile.html')
```

added this to settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

when I enter in stuff on my form it saves the url of the image to the database no problem but the image doesn't get saved into the media folder. I was under the impression that it created a media folder for you but it didn't. I then created a media folder and still nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012123/image-uploaded-but-not-saved-in-media-and-database-django

Comment: see here could be a permission issue if code is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045506/3904109

Answer (score 1):

You should be using request.FILES, not request.POST to access uploaded files. Please, see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) for more. And, it is convention that model names are Capitalized at each containing word, like `TrainerAbout`, not `trainerabout`.